# PayPal SetExpressCheckOut API issue

Tags: api, paypal

I'm trying to implement the PayPal API function for SetExpressCheckout. Below I put a part of my code that I am using to call the payment process on the PayPal side. Everything looks fine. At the last step of the checkout, i push the "Pay Now" button and the payment is processed. After that user is returnet to my original site and i got the Transaction ID, success message and token. It looks like evrything was finished fine, but in my PayPal account i dont see any transactions and I don’t get any money at all.

```
        $returnUrl = home_url("/wp-login.php?checkemail=registered&ppayment=done&price=".$package_price."&code=".$paypal_price_unit."&package=".$package_name."&pid=".$incomingpost);


        $requestParams = array(
           'RETURNURL' => $returnUrl,
           'CANCELURL' => home_url('/wp-login.php?checkemail=registered&ppayment=cancel')
        );

        // Sent item info
        $orderParams = array(
           'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => $package_price,
           'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT' => '0',
           'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => $paypal_price_unit,
           'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT' => $package_price
        );

        //send package info
        $item = array(
           'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0' => $paymentName,
           'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0' => $package_name,
           'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0' => $package_price,
           'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0' => '1'
        );


        //Call payment process
        $infos = array();
        $infos['USER'] = $paypal_api_user;
        $infos['PWD'] = $paypal_api_pwd;
        $infos['SIGNATURE'] = $paypal_api_signature;
        if($paypal_sandbox == 1){$sandstatus = true;}else{$sandstatus = false;}



        $paypal = new Paypal($infos,$sandstatus);
        $response = $paypal -> request('SetExpressCheckout',$requestParams + $orderParams + $item);


        if(is_array($response) && $response['ACK'] == 'Success') { 
            // We will redirecting now.
            $token = $response['TOKEN']; 

            //Save DB before redirect.
            $trans_post = array(
                'post_status' => 'pending',
                'post_type' => 'retransactions',
                'post_title' => $token,
            );
            $new_post_id = wp_insert_post( $trans_post );
            add_post_meta($new_post_id, 'webburemap_payment_user', $user_id);
            add_post_meta($new_post_id, 'webburemap_payment_amount', $package_price);
            add_post_meta($new_post_id, 'webburemap_payment_package_id', $package_IDNO);
            add_post_meta($new_post_id, 'webburemap_payment_package_transtype', 'NewPackage');



            if($paypal_sandbox == 0){
            $commit = '&useraction=commit';
            header( 'Location: https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=' . urlencode($token) . $commit ); //PayPal Pay Now
            }else{
            header( 'Location: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=' . urlencode($token) );
            }
            die();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the Express Checkout Token and the Transaction ID that you are getting back and I will take a look at it on my side to see what may be happening.  Also make sure that you are pointing to the correct endpoint.  If you are trying to process a live payment, make sure you are pointing towards the live site and not the sandbox.

Comment: I checked also all the settings , api, username, pass etc and everzthing is right!

Comment: Can you provide the Express Checkout Token, Transaction ID and what account the payment is coming from and what account it should be going to?